# Proving $\cos(a+b)=\cos a\cos b-\sin a\sin b$ starting from $\sin(a+b)$

Tags: trigonometry

The question is to prove the compound angle identity $\cos(a+b)=\cos(a)\cos(b)-\sin(a)\sin(b)$ starting from the $\sin$ compound angle identity. Before this, the task wants me to show that $\sin(\frac \pi 2 - x) = \cos(x)$ and I did not have any problems there. I guess I have to use this fact somehow so thats what I've tried:

$$\sin(a+b)=\sin(a)\cos(b)+\cos(a)\sin(b)$$
$$\sin\left(\frac \pi 2 - (a+b)\right)=\sin\left(\frac \pi 2\right)\cos(a+b)-\cos\left(\frac \pi 2\right)\sin(a+b)$$
$$\cos(a+b)=1\cos(a+b)-0\sin(a+b)$$
$$\cos(a+b)=\cos(a+b)$$
And that brings me nowhere. How can I prove this identity in the required way?

Comment: Try  expanding something like $\sin \left( \left(\frac {\pi}2-a\right)-b\right)$

Comment: thanks! this helped a lot

Comment: You may as well put your work in as a self-answer so the problem has an accepted answer.

Comment: allright, I already wondered how I could mark this question as solved (but I still have to wait two days until I can accept my own answer)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Direct calculation:$$\begin{align}\cos(a+b)&=\sin(\tfrac{\pi}{2}-a-b)\\&=\sin(\tfrac{\pi}{2}-a)\cos(-b)+\cos(\tfrac{\pi}{2}-a)\sin(-b)\\&=\cos a\cos b-\sin a\sin b.\end{align}$$

Answer (score 0):

Solution to the problem:
$$\sin((\frac \pi 2-a)-b)=\sin(\frac \pi 2 -a)\cos(b)-\cos(\frac \pi 2-a)\sin(b)$$
$$\sin((\frac \pi 2-a)-b)=\cos(a)\cos(b)-\sin(a)\sin(b)$$
$$\cos(a+b)=\cos(a)\cos(b)-\sin(a)\sin(b)$$